# How to get the value of last word in 1st row from command output

Tags: bash

I want to retrieve version number from `rsense -version` command. 
Output:

```
 rsense version 0.5.18 
 Usage: rsense <start|stop|restart>
```

**What I tried** :
If I save the output in one text file say output.txt and execute this command `awk 'NR == 1 {print $3}' /Users/poornima/Desktop/output.txt` . I am getting required result , i.e. `0.5.18`.

**But** `rsense -version | awk 'NR == 1 {print $3}'` is not working. Output:

```
    rsense version 0.5.18
    Usage: rsense <start|stop|restart>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like charm :).   Just wanted to know what does this mean  2>&1

Comment: I'll put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have `rsense`, but some programs write their version number to `stderr`, not `stdout`. Try:

```
rsense -version 2>&1 | awk 'NR == 1 {print $3}'
```

The meaning of `2>&1`: file streams are allocated numbers known as *file descriptors* (fds):

0 is `stdin`, by default the keyboard, redirection symbol `<` or `0<`

1 is `stdout`, by default the screen, redirection symbol `>` or `1>`

2 is `stderr`, by default the (unbuffered) screen, redirection symbol `2>`.

We can redirect to a file or to another file descriptor, prefixed by `&` (see `man dup2`).

So `2>&1` means, *redirect file descriptor 2 (stderr) to file descriptor 1 (stdout)*.  This is because pipes `|` only connect `stdout` on the left side to the `stdin` on the right - they don't use `stderr` (fd 2).

Here is an alternative which uses a `bash` array instead of the `awk` language (in theory this should be more efficient since it avoids loading and running an `awk` external process):

```
a=($(rsense -version 2>&1))
echo ${a[2]}        # arrays count from zero, awk counts from 1
```

By the way, your question asks for the *last* word.  In `bash` this would be:

```
echo ${a[-1]}         # assumes a recent version of bash
```

in `awk` would be:

```
awk '{print $NF}'
```

In `awk`, `$NF` gives the Number of Fields.

Comment: Thanks, You explained everything what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish the same goal using the standard Unix text processing tools.

#### Using `cut`

```
rsense --version | head -n 1 | cut -f3 -d' '
```

`head -n 1` outputs only the first line of its input.
`cut -f3 -d' '` outputs the `3`<sup>rd</sup> `f`ield of its input using space (`' '`) as field `d`elimiter (the default delimiter is the tab character).

#### Using `sed`

```
rsense --version | sed -n "1s/^rsense version //p"
```

There is no need for `head -n 1` any more because `sed` can be instructed what lines of the input to process.
`"1s/^rsense version //p"` is a `sed` programs. It tells `sed` to:

- `1` - the rest of the command applies only to the first line of the input;
- `s/^rsense version //` - `s`earch `^rsense version` and replace it with the empty string (the replacement string is provided between the second and the third `/` characters);
     the search string is a regular expression; `^` means the start of the string; the rest of the search string matches exactly the input string; all in all, the search string provided here means *"`rsense version` at the beginning of the line"* (please also note the space character after `version`).
- `p` - `p`rint the line after the replacement.

`-n` tells `sed` to not print its input (this is how it works by default). This suppress any output unless it is specifically required by using a `p` command (we want to print only the 1<sup>st</sup> line).

#### Using `bash` arrays

```
a=($(rsense --version | head -n 1))
echo ${a[2]}
```

By wrapping a command in `$()`, its output is captured and used instead of the command. After `rsense --version | head -n 1` is executed, the first line is the same as `a=(rsense version 0.5.18)`.
The braces around the text creates a bash array. Each work is an entry in the array. The arrays are numerically-indexed, starting with `0`. The third word of the text becomes the value at index `2`.
`${a[2]}` is the value stored in the array `a` at index `2` (the desired version number in this case).

Comment: OK, but this is just alternative ways of doing what the OP did and makes the same mistake.  You do not address the problem with `rsense` writing its version information to `stderr`.